# Apple сделала reject приложению

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple

Ребята, у меня в принципе простое приложение. Которое должно проигрывать музыку посредством AVPlayer'a. 
Вроде все хорошо, сделал чтобы она играла и тогда когда приложение идет в background.

Но я все сделал так как Apple говорит [Здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010209-CH1-VIDEO)

И так:

> First, declare your application provides specific background services
>   and must be allowed to continue running while in the background. To do
>   this, add the UIBackgroundModes key in your app's Info.plist file. Its
>   value is an array that contains one or more strings that identify
>   which background tasks your application supports. Specify the string
>   value audio to indicate the application plays audible content to the
>   user while in the background:

Плюс так:

> Listing 1  Setting the audio category to allow playback when the
>   screen locks or when the Ring/Silent switch is set to silent.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```

Но сегодня пришел реджект со словами:

> > June 17, 2015 at 6:12 AM От: Apple
> >     2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
> >     local notifications, etc.
> >     2.16 Details
>
> Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in
>   your Info.plist, but we were unable to play any audible content when
>   the application was running in the background.
>
> Next Steps
>
> The audio key is intended for use by applications that provide audible
>   content to the user while in the background, such as music player or
>   streaming audio applications. Please revise your app to provide
>   audible content to the user while the app is in the background or
>   remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>
> Resources
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try
>   testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to
>   reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources,
>   you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When
>   the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>   - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
>   - screenshots
>   - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
>   - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

Подскажите что не так делаю, запутался если честно((

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ревьювер не нашёл в вашем приложении воспроизведения звука в фоне. Покажите в комментариях к режекту наглядно, в каком случае юзер может стартовать воспроизведение и уйти в фон. Должна  быть как минимум явно видимая и узнаваемая кнопка старта воспроизведения. У вас таковая в наличии?

Comment: да тоже так подумал сначала. потом немножко подправил код и снова закинул бинарник на ревью, одновременно написав ревьюверу как запустить музыку и для чего нужно мне воспроизводить музыку в фоне. Жду их ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе все так как советовал товарищ  [Sega-Zero](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182662/sega-zero).

- в коде исправил мелкие недочеты
- написал развернутое сообщение интервьюеру, от том как правильно запустить и зачем, а главное когда нужно воспроизведения музыки в фоне

После чего получил одобрение в [apple store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-favorite-radio-list/id1003013203?mt=8).